# Metropolis Hastings for linear regression model

Tags: c, r, linear-regression, mcmc

I am trying to implement the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm for a simple linear regression in C (without use of other libraries (boost, Eigen etc.) and without two-dimensional arrays)*. For better testing of the code/evaluation of the trace plots, I have rewritten the code for R (see below) by keeping as much of the C-code as possible.

Unfortunately, the chains don't converge. I am wondering if

1. there is a mistake in the implementation itself?
2. "just" a bad choice of proposal distributions?

Assuming the latter, I am thinking about how to find good parameters of proposal distributions (currently I have picked arbitrary values) so that the algorithm works. Even with three parameters as in this case, it is quite hard to find suitable parameters. How does one normally handle this problem if say Gibbs sampling is not an alternative?

*I want to use this code for [Cuda](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone)

```
#### posterior distribution
logPostDensity <- function(x, y, a, b, s2, N)
{
sumSqError = 0.0
for(i in 1:N)
{
  sumSqError = sumSqError + (y[i] - (a + b*x[i]))^2
}
return(((-(N/2)+1) * log(s2)) + ((-0.5/s2) * sumSqError))

}

# x = x values
# y = actual datapoints
# N = sample size
# m = length of chain
# sigmaProp = uniform proposal for sigma squared
# paramAProp = uniform proposal for intercept
# paramBProp = uniform proposal for slope

mcmcSampling <- function(x,y,N,m,sigmaProp,paramAProp,paramBProp)
{

  paramsA = vector("numeric",length=m) # intercept
  paramsB = vector("numeric",length=m) # slope
  s2 = vector("numeric",length=m) # sigma squared

  paramsA[1] = 0
  paramsB[1] = 0
  s2[1] = 1

  for(i in 2:m)
  {

    paramsA[i] = paramsA[i-1] + runif(1,-paramAProp,paramAProp)

    if((logPostDensity(x,y,paramsA[i],paramsB[i],s2[i-1],N)
        - logPostDensity(x,y,paramsA[i-1],paramsB[i-1],s2[i-1],N))
       < log(runif(1)))
    {
      paramsA[i] = paramsA[i-1]
    }

    paramsB[i] = paramsB[i-1] + runif(1,-paramBProp,paramBProp)

    if((logPostDensity(x,y,paramsA[i],paramsB[i],s2[i-1],N)
        - logPostDensity(x,y,paramsA[i-1],paramsB[i-1],s2[i-1],N))
       < log(runif(1)))
    {
      paramsB[i] = paramsB[i-1]
    }

    s2[i] = s2[i-1] + runif(1,-sigmaProp,sigmaProp)

    if((s2[i] < 0) || (logPostDensity(x,y,paramsA[i],paramsB[i],s2[i],N)
                       - logPostDensity(x,y,paramsA[i],paramsB[i],s2[i-1],N))
       < log(runif(1)))
    {
      s2[i] = s2[i-1]
    }


  }

  res = data.frame(paramsA,paramsB,s2)
  return(res)
}


#########################################

set.seed(321)
x <- runif(100)
y <- 2 + 5*x + rnorm(100)

summary(lm(y~x))


df <- mcmcSampling(x,y,10,5000,0.05,0.05,0.05)


par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(df$paramsA[3000:5000],type="l",main="intercept")
plot(df$paramsB[3000:5000],type="l",main="slope")
plot(df$s2[3000:5000],type="l",main="sigma")
```

Comment: For one, for a formal Bayesian analysis, you need prior distributions on 'a', 'b', and 's2', which you're currently missing. But if you assume an uninformative prior, that shouldn't matter much.

I would try an adaptive Metropolis Hastings where you dynamically adjust your proposal ("Jump") distribution (i.e. the values of the `prop` variables) based on the current acceptance rate (which you would have to track with three counters). I think the reason you aren't getting convergence is that you're not exploring the full parameter space.

Comment: Thanks. As you suggested, I assume uninformative priors.  I have heard of adaptive MH sampling but I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. Basically, just keep track of your acceptance rate over a block of samples, take the ratio between that and a target acceptance rate (a common one is 0.44), and then multiply your proposal distribution width by that ratio. For example, for a given block of 100 samples, if you accept 88 of them then your actual acceptance rate is 0.88, so the ratio is 0.88/0.44=2, so you would multiply your `Prop` value for that parameter by 2. Here's an [example implementation](https://github.com/ashiklom/pecan/blob/master/modules/rtm/R/invert.custom.R).

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was one mistake in the intercept section (paramsA). Everything else was fine. I've implemented what Alexey suggested in his comments. Here's the solution:

```
pow <- function(x,y)
{
  return(x^y)
}


#### posterior distribution
posteriorDistribution <- function(x, y, a, b,s2,N)
{
sumSqError <- 0.0
for(i in 1:N)
{
  sumSqError <- sumSqError + pow(y[i] - (a + b*x[i]),2)
}
return((-((N/2)+1) * log(s2)) + ((-0.5/s2) * sumSqError))

}

# x <- x values
# y <- actual datapoints
# N <- sample size
# m <- length of chain
# sigmaProposalWidth <- width of uniform proposal dist for sigma squared
# paramAProposalWidth <- width of uniform proposal dist for intercept
# paramBProposalWidth <- width of uniform proposal dist for slope

mcmcSampling <- function(x,y,N,m,sigmaProposalWidth,paramAProposalWidth,paramBProposalWidth)
{

  desiredAcc <- 0.44

  paramsA <- vector("numeric",length=m) # intercept
  paramsB <- vector("numeric",length=m) # slope
  s2 <- vector("numeric",length=m) # sigma squared

  paramsA[1] <- 0
  paramsB[1] <- 0
  s2[1] <- 1

  accATot <- 0
  accBTot <- 0
  accS2Tot <- 0

  for(i in 2:m)
  {
    paramsA[i] <- paramsA[i-1] + runif(1,-paramAProposalWidth,paramAProposalWidth)
    accA <- 1
    if((posteriorDistribution(x,y,paramsA[i],paramsB[i-1],s2[i-1],N) - 
        posteriorDistribution(x,y,paramsA[i-1],paramsB[i-1],s2[i-1],N)) < log(runif(1)))
    {
      paramsA[i] <- paramsA[i-1]
      accA <- 0
    }


    accATot <- accATot + accA

    paramsB[i] <- paramsB[i-1] + runif(1,-paramBProposalWidth,paramBProposalWidth)
    accB <- 1
    if((posteriorDistribution(x,y,paramsA[i],paramsB[i],s2[i-1],N) - 
        posteriorDistribution(x,y,paramsA[i-1],paramsB[i-1],s2[i-1],N)) < log(runif(1)))
    {
      paramsB[i] <- paramsB[i-1]
      accB <- 0
    }

    accBTot <- accBTot + accB

    s2[i] <- s2[i-1] + runif(1,-sigmaProposalWidth,sigmaProposalWidth)
    accS2 <- 1

    if((s2[i] < 0) || (posteriorDistribution(x,y,paramsA[i],paramsB[i],s2[i],N) - 
                       posteriorDistribution(x,y,paramsA[i],paramsB[i],s2[i-1],N)) < log(runif(1)))
    {
      s2[i] <- s2[i-1]
      accS2 <- 0
    }

    accS2Tot <- accS2Tot + accS2

    if(i%%100==0)
    {

      paramAProposalWidth <- paramAProposalWidth * ((accATot/100)/desiredAcc)
      paramBProposalWidth <- paramBProposalWidth * ((accBTot/100)/desiredAcc)
      sigmaProposalWidth <- sigmaProposalWidth * ((accS2Tot/100)/desiredAcc)

      accATot <-  0
      accBTot <-  0 
      accS2Tot <-  0

    }


  }
    res <- data.frame(paramsA,paramsB,s2)
    return(res)

}
```